# How to send first value from two value in angular to node?

Tags: javascript, angular

Click on button I got two `folderid`, now I want to send only first folderid in service how it is possible ?

See below screenshot click on folder-1(folderid is 1230) it opens and shows four folders inside folder-1 using folderid. Now I click on folder-1-1(folderid is 1231), but it takes two folderids 1231 and 1230 both see in console any possibility to get only one folderid or else any other possibility to send only first folderid to server side ?

[image]

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let folder of folderObjs" (click)="getFolderName(folder.folderid)">{{folder.folderName}}
  <div *ngFor="let pattern of patternObj" (click)="getFolderName(pattern.folderid)">
    {{pattern.folderName}}
  </div>
</div>
```

TS

```
getFolderName(folderid){
   console.log(folderid); // 1231
                             1230
   this.userService.getFolderName({'folderid': folderid}).subscribe(
    (data) => {
      console.log(data.payload); 
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the inner click bubbles out to the parent - this should fix the problem:

```
<div *ngFor="let folder of folderObjs" (click)="getFolderName($event, folder.folderid)">{{folder.folderName}}
  <div *ngFor="let pattern of patternObj" (click)="getFolderName($event, pattern.folderid)">
    {{pattern.folderName}}
  </div>
</div>
```

and

```
getFolderName(e, folderid){
   e.cancelBubble = true;
   this.userService.getFolderName({'folderid': folderid}).subscribe(
    (data) => {
      console.log(data.payload); 
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I'm following what's wrong but...

I think when you click on `folder-1-1`, it also clicks on `folder-1` since that's it's parent.

Try this:

```
<div *ngFor="let folder of folderObjs">
  <span (click)="getFolderName(folder.folderid)">{{folder.folderName}}</span>
  <div *ngFor="let pattern of patternObj" (click)="getFolderName(pattern.folderid)">
    {{pattern.folderName}}
  </div>
</div>
```